# Bitcoin, Keepassx from repositories?

Tags: repositories

I´m new to Elementary - I use Freya at the moment.
Now I´m testing Loki virtualised.

In Loki I can´t install bitcoin-qt and keepassx from the ressources.
Adding the repositories also won´t work.

What do I have to do? If this works, I will upgrade to Loki this afternoon...

Comment: Ok Keepassx I found in the repositories.

But for Bitcoin I found that:
https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin

And add-apt-repository doesn´t work!

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```